# Adding any email address under Recipient in Workflow Actions - Email Alerts

Tags: workflow, email-alert

Is it possible to add any email address for the workflow action email alert recipient that is nowhere related to the contact, or workflow that is being triggered. Like typing it out. Is it a good idea to add the email in a public group and select it here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want any Email recipient that is not added in the contact then you can use `Additional Emails` section where you can add up to 5 additional recipient for testing purpose and you don't have to add them in contact.

[image]

Comment: That is if you want to cc someone. I don't want to cc anyone, or i just want to mail a custom contact A when another contact B does something on salesforce. But I don't want B to know that I mailed A regarding the change they did.

Answer (score 0):

To add the email recipient to Email Alerts which are not the salesforce user or contact. You can Use the **Additional Emails** option.
One thing that you need to consider here is if you have already added any user or contact in the email alert and then you are adding a Additional Emails, then it will be added as **CC email**.

To add the emails directly to To, you can create another email alert where you have not added any user or contact and then add your emails in **Additional Emails**. It will be added as **To**.